# Ikea solklint wiring help

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, light-fixture

I'm trying to install an IKEA Solklint and the wires do not easily match up with my existing fixture.

1. Where do I attach the ground wire? Will any screw be fine?
2. Is the red or white wire the live one?

[image]
<sup>Click to embiggen</sup>

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Ground**

The ground wire should be attached to the metal box, ideally by a screw that is located in the back/top of the box.  Since I don't really see one, you could also use one of the square-head screws attaching that metal mounting strip to the box.  Above all, the ground wire just needs to have a solid electrical connection to the metal (I am assuming here that since I don't see a ground wire entering the box, there is metal electrical conduit serving as a ground connection back to the main panel).

**Live/Phase & Neutral**

Common wiring practice in North America says that the red wire here would be the live leg and the white is neutral.  However, it is always best to use a voltage tester to verify (with the circuit on and the bare ends of the wires safely away from other wires/boxes/hands/children/pets).

Comment: I wouldn't use one of those square-drive screws for the ground - their one and only job should be to keep the light attached to the box. There should be a hole threaded 10-32 in the back of the box for the grounding screw. Since the wiring is in conduit, _any_ color other that white or grey (neutrals), or bare, green, green/yellow (ground) is a hot. _Some_ electricians will have a habit of making red a switched hot, but it's not required.  Still, a +1 though!

Comment: You're right about that screw - better to add another in the box than double-duty a mounting screw.